# How to use methods in ObjectContext class, if I use IObjectSet<T> for unit test?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using EF4 with POCO and trying to make it testable architecture.
So I create IObjectContext interface as follow :

```
public interface IObjectContext
    {
        IObjectSet<Employee> Employees { get; }
        IObjectSet<Team> Teams { get; }
        void Commit();
    }
```

Then I changed type of properties to IObjectSet in my real ObjectContext class as follow :

```
public partial class HRManagementEntities : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        // skip some codes here...........

        public IObjectSet<Employee> Employees
        {
            get { return _employees  ?? (_employees = CreateObjectSet<Employee>("Employees"));         
        }
        private IObjectSet<Employee> _employees;

        public IObjectSet<Team> Teams
        {
            get { return _teams  ?? (_teams = CreateObjectSet<Team>("Teams")); }
        }
        private IObjectSet<Team> _teams;

        public void Commit()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

In my service layer, consume EF like this :

```
public class Service
    {
         private IObjectContext ctx;

         public HRService(IObjectContext ctx)
         {
            this.ctx = ctx;
         }

         public List<Team> GetAllTeams()
         {
            return ctx.Teams.ToList();
         }
    }
```

Here is my problem, How to call methods in ObjectContext for example, ApplyCurrentValues(), ExecuteStoreCommand(), and so on... ?

Do I need to implement those methods in the IObjectContext to use?

**EDIT**

As RPM's advice, I created following extension method for ApplyCurrentValues() method, another methods could be extended in same way.

```
public static T UpdateModel<T>(this IObjectSet<T> iObjectSet, T currentEntity) where T : class
        {
            ObjectSet<T> objectSet = iObjectSet as ObjectSet<T>;
            if (objectSet == null || currentEntity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
            return objectSet.ApplyCurrentValues(currentEntity);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create **extension methods** for the methods you need, and cast the `IObjectSet` to `ObjectSet`.

For instance, if you need to do `.Include` (eager loading), use this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path)
    {
        var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;

        if (objectQuery != null)
        {
            objectQuery.Include(path);
        }

        return source;
    }
```

You could *probably* do the same thing for `IObjectContext`, but not sure why you are even mocking this out. You should not expose the OC to outside the repository, only the repository should know about the OC.

In your example, your service is calling ctx.Teams on the entities/repository.

IMO your service should be calling ctx.Find, which would be strongly-typed (via generics) to the Teams object context. (IRepository)

A common trap is to over-mock things. Don't mock everything just for the sake of it, mock the functionality which you require for unit testing.

If you want to abstract out the Object Context then use the Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: Actually, as my team members are not familiar with ORM at all, I was going to make architecture as simple as possible. That's why I tried to use ObjectContext as UnitOfWork without using Repository pattern.

Comment: The codes you showed me is I already tried, but when it comes to IObjectContext, could not find out any solution without using repository pattern. If possible, can you show me some sample codes?

Comment: You can make your architecture simple, but having `public interface IObjectContext` is not the way to go IMO. I'm not saying you need to have a crazy/robust repository in place, a simple one with methods `public ICollection<Team> GetTeams` will do. My point is, calling  methods like `ApplyCurrentValues(), ExecuteStoreCommand(),` should be a decision made by the DAL, not your service - therefore there is no reason to expose the method via the `IObjectContext` interface. Know what i mean?

Comment: Also, looking at your code, `Service` **is** almost a Repository. I would be renaming `HRService` to `HRRepository`, and changing `IObjectContext` to `ObjectContext`. That is the simplest solution here.